# Google Sheets - How to count 1 column dependent on the values of another column in the same row

Tags: google-sheets

I work for a company that has various franchises and we are trying to examine a specific issues by locations, relating to our staff members ability to use our app. I am trying to use the countifs function, which has worked for similar problems in the past, but it is not working here.

For example, if we have an office in New York, Dallas and Los Angeles and the options for employees unable to access the app are 'User Error' or 'Software Error', how do I make a function that shows, for example, only employees in New York who check off 'User Error'?

What I've tried so far is `=countifs(Franchise, "New York", Reason, "User Error")` - where 'Franchise' and 'Reason' are predefined ranges), but it returns an error - "Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size." How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information), clearly indicating the expected outcome?